# How to Get Last insert UUID from Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, uuid

How To Fetch The Last Insert UUID in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a "table" (that means your the class extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`) then the last inserted **primary key** with a generated key is automatically returned when calling the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::insert`-method:

```
$personTable = new My_Model_DbTable_Person()
$addressTable = new My_Model_DbTable_Address()

$personId = $personTable->insert(array(
    "name" => "John",
    "familyname" => "Doe",
));

$addressTable->insert(array(
    "person_id" => $personId,
    "street" => "Some Street",
    "city" => "Gotham City",
));
```

There's more on that method in the Zend Reference of [`Zend_Db_Table`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert.key-auto)

If you're using the database adapter directly (class extends `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract`, instantiated using `Zend_DB::factory` or instantiated the database using application resources) then there is the method `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::lastInsertId` which is a bit more flexible. See the Zend reference of [`Zend_Db_Adapter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.lastinsertid) for further information.

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory(...);

$db->insert("person", array(
    "name" => "John",
    "familyname" => "Doe",    
));

$personId = $db->lastInsertId();

$db->insert("address", array(
    "person_id" => $personId,
    "street" => "Some Street",
    "city" => "Gotham City",  
));
```